# LibGDX guidance - sprite tracing 2D infinite random bezier curve

Tags: libgdx, sprite, bezier, spline, plane

I've been able to apply a smooth animation to my sprite and control it using the accelerometer. My sprite is fixed to move left and right along the x-aixs.

From here, I need to figure out how to create a vertical infinite wavy line for the sprite to attempt to trace. the aim of my game is for the user to control the sprite's left/right movement with the accelerometer in an attempt to trace the never ending wavy line as best they can, whilst the sprite and camera both move in a vertical direction to simulate "moving along the line." It would be ideal if the line was randomly generated.

I've researched about splines, planes, bezier curves etc, but I can't find anything that seems to relate close enough to what I'm trying to achieve.

I'm just seeking some guidance as to what methods I could possibly use to achieve this. Any ideas?

Comment: can you post some references what you want to achieve..

Comment: Hmm, not really, as I came up with the concept myself. In basic terms, I want a user to be able to control a sprite to trace a line. I will eventually record how accurately the user was able to trace the line with the sprite. Sorry I can't get any references- that's kinda what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use sum of 4 to 5 sine waves (each with different amplitude, wavelength and phase difference). All 3 of those parameters could be random.

The resulting curve would be very smooth (since it is primarily sinusoidal) yet it'll look random (it's time period would be LCM of all 4 to 5 random wavelengths which is a huge number).

So the curve won't repeat for a long time, yet it will not be hard on memory. Concerning computational complexity, you can always tune it by changing number of sine terms with FPS.

It should look like this.
[image]

It's really easy to implement too. (even I could generate above image.. haha)

Hope this helps. Maths rocks. :D

(The basic idea here is a finite [Fourier series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series) which I think should be ideal for your use case)

---

**Edit:**

You can create each term like this and assign random values to all terms.

```
public class SineTerm {

    private float amplitude;
    private float waveLength;
    private float phaseDifference;

    public SineTerm(float amplitude, float waveLength, float phaseDifference) {
        this.amplitude = amplitude;
        this.waveLength = waveLength;
        this.phaseDifference = phaseDifference;
    }

    public float evaluate(float x) {
        return amplitude * (float) Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * x / waveLength + phaseDifference);
    }

}
```

Now create an array of `SineTerm`s and add all values returned by `evaluate(x)` (use one coordinate of sprite as input). Use the output as other coordinate of sprite. You should be good to go.

The real trick would be in tuning those random numbers.

Good luck.

Comment: Hi Tanmay, thanks for your in depth answer! I feel like it's a bit over my head, but no worries, I will research the key terms to get a better understanding of the concept of Fourier series. Right now though, I don't have any idea how to actually turn this ace idea into code... if you've got any pointers on that front, let me know. Cheers.

Comment: Glad to know that it helped. I have updated the answer, so check it out. Regards.

Comment: Thanks Tanmay- you've really given me a good head start. I'm committed to figuring this out, so I'll take what you've given me and build from there. Thanks again!

Comment: Hi @TanmayPatil I have used the sineTerm class but I dont know how to create a sprite with wavy effect using evaluate(x) .please help me

Comment: Creating a sprite out of it would be a completely different problem, which I don't think can be explained in comments. I think you should post it as a different new question with a link to this question.