# How to create a random wave in libgdx

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, libgdx

I need to create a random wave ..

[LibGDX guidance - sprite tracing 2D infinite random bezier curve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21980045/libgdx-guidance-sprite-tracing-2d-infinite-random-bezier-curve)
From this link I learned that using sineTerm gives a random curve..

But in libgdx I dont know how to position x and y of the sprite for the evaluted values.Its hard to get ...

Could you guys .. help me in understanding the maths and libgdx sprite distribution for wave

**Update :**

[image]

I dont know how to draw this in libgdx Help me friends

Comment: Do you want to move the sprite according to the wave or do you want a wavy shaped sprite?

Comment: Do you understand functions? For example: **f(x) = 2x** For any given x value, one value is output, and that is y. In this case **f(x) = A*sin(B*x+C) + D*sin(E*x+F) + G*sin(H*x+I) + J*sin(K*x+L) + M*sin(N*x+O)**, where all the big letters are random constants.

Comment: @Tanmay Patil I need to create wave in top and bottom

Comment: @Tenfour04 I understood function but i am unable to implement in libgdx java class

Comment: I don't think we can help you any more than that without a detailed picture of what you're trying to achieve. Like, I have no idea if you are trying to draw a bunch of deformed sprites to make hills like in Tiny Wings, or you want to distribute a bunch of coins in a pattern where they will look like waves if you connect the dots, etc. You didn't answer Tanmay Patil's question at all.

Comment: Sorry @Tenfour04 I will create a image pls

Comment: It would take me a few hours to explain it in detail...time I don't have. The hills will be made of many quadrilaterals, where the bottom is like a rectangle, and the top two corners are vertically shifted. Choose an even horizontal spacing and that gives you x coordinates for all of the quads' corners. plug them into the formula to get the y coordinate for the top vertices. The bottom vertices are all aligned with the bottom of the screen. As the scene moves, calculate which quads will need to be drawn to cover the whole screen, and modify Sprites from a pool with `setVertices`.

Comment: Look at the source code to understand how `setVertices` works. You'll also need to do some math to get the UV coordinates to line up. See here for an example in cocos2d to see the general idea: http://www.raywenderlich.com/32954/how-to-create-a-game-like-tiny-wings-with-cocos2d-2-x-part-1

Comment: As a starting point, you could set up some Sprites so they are all lined up in a row and can infinitely scroll. As sprites go off the left of the screen, add them to a pool and pull sprites from the pool as you need new ones for the right side of the screen. Once you have that working, you just need to modify the y position of the top two vertices of each sprite, using the formula.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71369/discussion-between-android-developer-and-tenfour04).